# mod_rewrite with hyphens and varying word lengths

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to turn this url `www.website.com/clients/index.php?display=client-name` into `www.website.com/clients/client-name`.

But I'm having problems because the client name often varies in length. It could be anywhere from one word to five+ words, but they are always separated by **hyphens**:

- client
- client-name
- the-estate-of-client-name
- etc

I have successfully written several other urls for this site, but can't get this one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphens shouldn't matter unless you're using a regular expression that won't match them. You can simply include `-` in the expression. For example, if you had `([A-Za-z0-9]+)`, then you just need to add `-` so that it's `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`. You should also make sure that whatever you are matching isn't for an existing resource (like index.php), since you want those to just get served. So something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?clients/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /clients/index.php?display=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems (to me) that you are doing it other way around - the second should be your human readable links url and the first should be the result of mod_rewrite processing.
2) It does NOT matter how long your client-name is as long as you know it's start and end points - here start should be
`/clients/(.*)$`
and should be rewritten to
`/clients/index.php?display=$1`

Reading a little more on regex will help you

Comment: I tried:

RewriteRule ^/clients/(.*)$ /clients/index.php?display=$1

And then visited:

www.website.com/clients/the-estate-of-client-name

And got a 404 Error?

Comment: @Amanda DID it rewrite the url (internally)? Your web server log should show which actual file it can not find AFTER rewrite.

Comment: Upon further investigation-- the URL is working, however the "display" variable is reset to "index.php" instead of "client-name"-- therefore causing my PHP code to display nothing (since "index.php" is not a valid client name). Is this an error with the mod_rewrite, or an error with my PHP code?

Comment: @Amanda It happens because your rewritten url gets processed again and rewritten further, I think that [L] after the rule will help you.  http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/mod_rewrite-quick-reference-and-cheat-sheet/

Comment: I appreciate your help. The [L] at the end did not fix the variable problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @Amanda What is the result now?
I would have thought that 
`^/clients/(.*)$ /clients/index.php?display=$1 [L]`
should be enough, but you can check if there are any other flags you may need. (I don't have access to web server that I can play with at the moment)

Comment: It is still setting display equal to "index.php". I'm trying some other flags, but I'm obviously not very well-versed in this so no dice thus far.

Comment: @Amanda Give this a try: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != /clients/index.php
RewriteRule ^/clients/(.*)$ /clients/index.php?req=$1 [L,PT]
And generally read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thanks-- your final suggested kept giving me a 500 error, but I finally solved the problem with this code: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l RewriteRule ^clients/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ clients/index.php?display=$1 [L]